# How to select an bounded combo box value and display its value into an Label Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, combobox

I have an ComboBox1 which is bounded by EmpId which is an primary key also..
when i used the code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      label5.Text = comboBox1.DisplayMember;
}
```

it gives an error-

> Column 'EmpId' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'Emp008' is already
>   present.

My question is How to select that bounded value and display it into an Label text..

Comment: Can you please show your Code.

Comment: Can you show the code where you add your rows to the `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void bind()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AttendanceManagmentSystem.Properties.Settings.Cons1"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select EmpId from EmpDetail", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "EmpId";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "EmpId";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label5.Text = comboBox1.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code `comboBox1.SelectedValue` to get selected value or for text you can use this code `comboBox1.SelectedText`

Comment: When we use ComboBox1.SelectedText it gives an error-Cannot bind to the property or column EmpId on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember